# How to subset a matrix for multiple conditions using loop in R?

Tags: r

Example matrix (Input)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWOlh.png)

```
  Species   PH  PNH
    A   1   10
    B   2   11
    C   3   12
    D   4   13
    E   5   14
    F   6   15
    G   7   16
    H   8   17
    I   9   18
```

I want to subset a matrix in R using sets of multiple conditions-

```
Subset 1 for Condition 1: PH >= 5 and PNH >= 15
Subset 2 for Condition 2: PH >= 3 and PNH >= 13

S1<-subset(Input, Input$PH >= 5 & Input$PNH >= 15)
S2<-subset(Input, Input$PH >= 3 & Input$PNH >= 13)
```

For each column (PH and PNH) of all subsets (S1 and S2), I have to calculate shannon diversity-

```
S1_shannon<-diversity(S1, 2, index="shannon")
S2_shannon<-diversity(S2, 2, index="shannon")
```

So my question is "How to subset a matrix for multiple conditions in loop as shown in example?"
so that I can use generated subsets to calculate diversity.
I would appreciate any help from the community.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily subset as so:

```
sub_1<-df %>% 
  filter(PH>=5,PNH>=15)
sub_2<-df %>% 
       filter(PH>=3,PNH>=13)
```

I don't know about `shannon diversity.`
The assumption is you'll make it a `data.frame` first.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have to apply many conditions in my original data frame and I do not want to repeat same lines every time for each condition. Would it be possible using a loop?